# php exec mysqldump doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, shell

I'm trying to run a mysqldump from my php file using exec(). File is located in my website's www directory and I'm accessing it from browser. But, no matter what I try, I'm simply not getting ANY results and no sql file is created.

Here's my command:

```
$export = exec("/usr/bin/mysqldump -u MY_USERNAME -pMY_PASS DATABASE_NAME products > /path/to/www/directory/sync/products.sql");
```

exec() is enabled. sync directory permissions are 777.

If I use the same command, but add `$output, $return_var` like this:

```
$export = exec("/usr/bin/mysqldump -u MY_USERNAME -pMY_PASS DATABASE_NAME products > /path/to/www/directory/sync/products.sql", $output, $return_var);
```

`$output` is an empty array and `$return_var` echoes 127.

Path to mysqldump is correct:

```
root@server [~]# which mysqldump
/usr/bin/mysqldump
root@server [~]#
```

If I run the command from console, it works just fine and the new file gets created in my sync directory.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I'm missing here? The script used to work just fine until we moved to a new server...

Comment: non-zero exit code indicates failure. are you sure your webserver user has the rights to write files where?

Comment: @MarcB I know it indicates a failure... And that's the beauty of it - how to debug it? As for webserver user rights to write files - shouldn't that be sorted with CHMOD 777 on the sync directory? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching all over the place and have stumbled upon something that turned out to solve my problem.

Instead of using

```
$export = exec("/usr/bin/mysqldump -u MY_USERNAME -pMY_PASS DATABASE_NAME products > /path/to/www/directory/sync/products.sql");
```

I am now using this and **THIS WORKS**:

```
$export = exec('mysqldump -u MY_USERNAME -pMY_PASS DATABASE_NAME products -r "/path/to/www/directory/sync/products.sql"');
```

Using path to `mysqldump` doesn't make a difference. Using `options` (in this case `-r`) solved it for me, although I don't really understand why the original solution didn't work.

Maybe worth mentioning - I noticed that I can't import a database using the standard `mysql -u -p db < table.sql` - running that command just shows me help instructions, as if I ran `mysql -?`. I'm not sure if this is specific to me and my server, but maybe the solution above helps someone in a similar situation.